# Python CSV, blank rows

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a csv file with ping times. Below I have the code to get the ping time and put it in the csv file. Unfortunately the format in the csv files is a little messed up.

```
import subprocess as sp
import csv

ip = "216.52.241.254"
status,result = sp.getstatusoutput("ping -n 1 -w 1000 " + ip + ' | grep -o time=[0-9]* | grep -o [0-9]*')

with open('C:/PingData/test.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    #result = int(result)
    cwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    cwriter.writerow(result)
```

The csv file that this code is printing looks like: [image]

What it should look like is this:
[image]

I'm looking for a solution/reason why there are extra blank rows being printed, and why there are spaces between the numbers (I've tried passing them in as integers to no avail)

Comment: Post the actual text of the csvfile.  Screenshots of spreadsheets just hide the real issue.

Comment: The code you've posted only writes a one row csv file. Please show your real code and add some sample `result` data that would allow us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writerow` expects a list, so it takes your string as a list of characters.  Put it in brackets to treat it as a list of a single string:

```
    cwriter.writerow([result])
```